# How to put function as a parameter into existing function

Tags: python, function, arguments

for a programming class we need to program three methods for calculating the root of a mathematical function, in the code below I used the "method of bisection".

The code itself seems to be working so far.

Now I want to get this code as a function, so I can input the boundaries, the tolerated deviation of the y-value as well as the mathematical function and it's variable as arguments.

But inserting for example "2 * x + 1" as the mathematical function and "x" as the variable of course doesn't work...
I am not that familiar with python yet and didn't find a solution online so far.
So maybe you can help me out? :)

```
from math import *

# Bisection method
def Bisection ( a , b , y_tolerance , f , variable ) :

    # Define function.
    def f ( variable ) :

        return f

    # Mean for bisection.
    mean = ( a + b ) / 2

    # while-loop as long as y-value is bigger than wished tolerance.
    while abs( f ( mean ) ) > 10 ** ( - ( y_tolerance ) ) :

        # Recalculate mean for each iteration.
        mean = ( a + b ) / 2

        # If sign of y-values changes, cut interval in half from left.
        if f ( mean ) * f ( b ) < 0 :

            a = mean

        # If sign of y-values doesn't change, cut interval in half from right.
        elif f( mean ) * f ( b ) > 0 :

            b = mean

    # Print mean as approximation of the first root in the interval.
    else :

        print ( mean )

Bisection ( -1 , 0 , 2 * x + 1 , x )
```

Thanks to everyone who is willing to help me. :)

Comment: Why did you redefine `f` to be a no-op function after accepting it as a parameter?

Comment: what's the point of `f` function?

Comment: f function should be the mathematical expression so that I could just insert in in the Bisection-function. 
I've written most of the code first, after that I wanted to have a function for the whole code. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't construct the `f` function in such a way as to pass it into your bisection function; the business you were trying with `f` and `variable` was creative but bears no resemblance to how functions are constructed in Python.  :)

Here's how to do it:

```
from math import fabs
from typing import Callable


def bisect(
    a: float,
    b: float,
    y_tolerance: float,
    f: Callable[[float], float],
) -> float:
    """Bisection method."""

    # Mean for bisection.
    mean = (a + b) / 2

    # while-loop as long as y-value is bigger than wished tolerance.
    while fabs(f(mean)) > 10 ** (-y_tolerance):
        # Recalculate mean for each iteration.
        mean = (a + b) / 2

        # If sign of y-values changes, cut interval in half from left.
        if f(mean) * f(b) < 0:
            a = mean
        # If sign of y-values doesn't change, cut interval in half from right.
        elif f(mean) * f(b) > 0:
            b = mean

    # Return mean as approximation of the first root in the interval.
    return mean


print(bisect(-1, 0, 0.1, lambda x: 2 * x + 1))
```

As an alternative to the `lambda x: 2 * x + 1` to construct the function parameter you could also do:

```
def f(x: float) -> float:
    return 2 * x + 1

print(bisect(-1, 0, 0.1, f))
```

These two are almost exactly equivalent; `lambda` is just a handy shortcut to create a small function in a single expression.

Comment: So defining the function beforehand or using the ```lambda``` is the only or most simple way to use a mathematical expression as an argument?

I didn't know ```lambda```, so thank you very much so far! :)

Comment: Not all mathematical expressions are functions, but for a function (which is the case you're talking about), yes, expressing it as a function rather than as some other thing is ideal.  (You could technically express it as a string and then write a lot of code to convert the string back into a function so that you can evaluate it, or something like that -- but just represent a function as a function, it's a lot easier.)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot. I meant "function" in my answer more like "mathematical expression". Sorry, sometimes I confuse some words, not a native english speaker. :)